# Tool to Document TM1 Processes

Tags: documentation, cognos, cognos-tm1

We have an inherited data warehouse with a lot of processes and no documentation. 
Has anyone used or knows about a software tool that can automatically document all our TM1 processes?

Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, of course it's "off topic". This site is getting way too anal in my opinion. "Oh no, that's a violation of The Rules (TM) Stack Exchange, not allowed!", "No that's a Breach Of Sacred Etiquette (TM) Stack Exchange". The guy was asking for whether there was any way of doing something that isn't built in to the system concerned. Naturally, this would involve using a tool. How on earth is someone supposed to ask a question when they have no idea where to even start, as was the case here. This attitude will kill StackExchange eventually. Not now, while alternatives are few, but eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of one person (a {cough} friend of mine) who has written an admin helper tool which includes a process documenter using the API, but it's not available for general release. It is certainly possible to do it, but it will take you some time. A ***lot*** of time if you don't already know the API.

If you want to avoid the time and get a bunch of other features into the bargain you could look at a commercial product called [Cubewise Pulse](http://cubewise.com/cwtools/pulse). I use it, not so much for the TI documenter (though it has a very powerful feature there as well, including showing parameters, variables, etc) but as a replacement for TM1 Top / the version 10 admin tools that replaced TM1 Top. In fact it has full model documentation features.

The downside? It's not free, and it's not all that cheap. But it is ***very*** useful if you have the budget.